# Multi-line indent in List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, multline

The following image is taken from MS Word which shows the list of figures in an exemplar thesis work. 
[image]

As can be seen in the above picture, the captions are aligned with the word 'Figure' if they have multi-line. Also notice that, they end at the right end of the page where they are aligned with roman and arabic numbers.

I have seen many different list-of-figure customizations built with latex; but never found such a specific configuration even with an exhaustive search on the internet.

Is there a previous topic or a similar example to provide such a case?

Best regards

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It should be doable, if not recommendable, with a package like `titletoc` (which comes with `titlesec`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with the `titletoc` package. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\contentsmargin{0mm}
\titlecontents{figure}[0mm]%
    {\makebox{Figure\enspace}}%
    {\makebox{\thecontentslabel.\enspace}}%
    {\makebox{.~}}%
    {\enspace\dotfill\enspace\thecontentspage\vspace{2mm}}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\begin{figure}
\caption{Some figure.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Some other figure, but with really really long caption that goes on more than only one line.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Again another figure, just to have another example to make sure everything is as it should be.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]
If you want more examples or more details, see the [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc).

Comment: Excellent work, thanks a lot..